# Discrete math induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am trying to solve a induction proof and i got stuck at the end, some help would be great. This is the question and what i did so far:

Statement: For all integers $n \geq 5$ we have $2^n \geq n^2$.

Proof: Induction over $n$. Introduce the name $A(n)$ for the statement $2^n \geq n^2$. We shall prove, by mathematical induction that $\forall n \geq 5 : A(n)$.

1. $A(n)$ and test with $5$ so that $A(5): 2^5 ≥ 5^2 \implies 32 ≥ 25$ (true)
2. Assume $A(p)$ so that we have $A(p): 2^p \geq p^2$ and we want to prove $A(p+1): 2^{p+1} \geq (p+1)^2$.

$2^{p+1} \geq (p+1)^2 \iff 2 \cdot 2^p ≥ p^2 + 2p + 1$, with the assumption $2^p \geq p^2$ we get $2p^2 ≥ p^2 + 2p + 1$,         it is here where i dont know how to continue to prove the statement

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't try to do “if and only if”:

$$
2^{p+1}=2\cdot 2^p\ge2p^2
$$
because of the induction hypothesis. Now, try proving that, for $p\ge5$, $2p^2\ge(p+1)^2$

Hint: this is equivalent to $p^2-2p-1\ge0$, which is true when $p\ge\dots$

Comment: i dont understand what u mean with this comment, it just looks like you repeated what i have already done? i dont know how to continue from here

Comment: @haha150 Can you say that $p^2-2p-1\ge0$ for $p\ge5$? Yes, because the inequality is satisfied when $p\ge 1+\sqrt{2}$ and $5>1+\sqrt{2}$. My initial comment is because you don't want to “solve an inequality”, but just verifying it holds for certain values of $p$.

Comment: sorry i dont see the connection of this and what im trying to prove, i also dont know where u got p2−2p−1≥0 from, i cant figure out the answer

Comment: @haha150 You want to prove $2p^2\ge(p+1)^2$, don't you? Expand the right-hand side and transport.

Comment: Yes and I get 2p2≥p2+2p+1 but don't know what else to do

Comment: @haha150 Transport to the left-hand side; you get $p^2-2p-1\ge0$. Can you go on now?

Comment: Omg i see now what you meant, so that concludes the proof too I assume

Answer (score 0):

$$2p^n \ge 2p^2 = p^2 + p^2$$
Here $p^2 = 2p + (p-2)p \ge 2p + 1 $ for (p > 4) since $(p-2)p > 1$ for p > 4

So $$2^{p + 1} = 2\,2^p > 2 p^2 = p^2 + p^2 \ge p^2 + 2p + 1 = (p + 1)^2$$